# Illustrator: Mouse hover with selection tool (V) does not highlight group objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I seem to have hit a hotkey combo by accident or changed some preferences in Illustrator and I can't figure out what.

When using the selection tool (V) and hovering over an object (Object selection by path only is disabled), the blue outline would normally show all objects which are grouped with the object I was hovering over.  This "preview" is very useful for me to be able to see groups.

Now, when I hover over an object with the selection tool, all that I can see is the outline for that one object.  To see if it is grouped with other objects and what those objects are, I have to now actually click to select the object and then the entire grouped set is selected as expected.  This behaviour was not the norm as of yesterday.  This seems trivial but when I have literally hundreds of groups in a file, it is extremely tedious to go through and click on each one to see the current group rather than quickly hover.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: is this a newer setting (since cs6) you use? I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and found this page, but nothing here seemed to solve it.

I did some hunting and found that I had somehow pressed the shortcut for `Hide Edges` - or <kbd>cmd + H</kbd>.

You can toggle this by going to `View > Hide Edges`.

I must have accidentally hit <kbd>H</kbd> instead of <kbd>G</kbd>. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hoping you managed to find a solution by now xD.

I cam here because I had the same problem, I just pressed CMD + U and that worked for me!

Hope this helps somebody in the future.

Comment: it says on the other answer, cmd+H

Comment: This is a more accurate solution to the question because this solves the issue when hovering on the paths.

Comment: thanks user79649, command + U worked for me and now I can see objects highlighted and "anchor" and other words appear when i hover on things

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem - turning off Smart Guides solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try turning off "Snap to Grid" if you have it enabled.

Comment: Hey Averee! Welcome to GD.SE. If you can edit your answer to include where to find this setting, in it would be helpful for novice users.